# Rails controller not returning any information to front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

All right, so I'm sort of out of practice, but I've been banging my head against this for about a day now and I'm getting nowhere. I've got a model that basically just runs a giant dice roller and spits out some strings, and the controller's supposed to run it and send it over to the page for display. My server terminal seems to return all the text, but what I receive via ajax is undefined. When I try and p out the variable, I get a blank string.
Rails:

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def wound
    table = Table.new
    @wound = table.take_wound
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

Here's my js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(".button_to").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log("ayy")
      $.ajax({
        url: "/wound",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data+"!!")
          $(".response").text(data)
        }
      });
    });
});
```

If this isn't enough info just let me know and I'll answer any q's.

Thanks, internet.

Comment: render text: @wound ??

Comment: like @sethi alluded to, your dataType is text and you are returning something other than a `text` type.

Comment: Man I just realized that... @wound is spitting out as nilclass. It seems to be kind of a puts string hell, and I'm not actually getting a full string out of it, just a bunch of puts statements that are just running in succession. I think just rubber ducking it kind of helped. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have a view template setup to do something with `@wound`, and what type `@wound` is, but assuming you just want a basic text response (based on your client-side JS), and assuming `@wound` is that text as a string, you can change the render line to the following:

```
render text: @wound
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That helps! I just found out why I'm getting basically nothing, but once I fix what @wound is I'll try that out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails You should be telling the client that they’re requesting a format you support, not that you can’t find the right file.

I think this link will support you more understanding for rails respond format.

https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/respond-to-without-all-the-pain